# Separate tables on sql workbench rather than a single one

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have probably a banal question, but I need an advice.

I am working for the DBMS of a center, where there are two different types of customer: let's call them **customerOrdinary** and **customerSpecial**.

Of course they have attributes in common, like Name, Surname, date of birth...
And then **customerSpecial** has attributes that **customerOrdinary** does not have and *viceversa*.

customerSpecial and customerOrdinary are then connected to different tables: **customerOrdinary** is connected to table1, and **customerSpecial** is connected to table2 and table3

At this point, knowing that, I have 2 different ways possible:

**WAY 1:**

create a single table "customer" with all the common attributes, and then two other tables customerS and customerO with the same PK and other columns.

```
CUSTOMER
ID     DATEOFBIRTH.  NAME.   SURNAME.   TYPE
01.    1989/07/12.   Sal.     Dallow.    S
02.    1987/09/12.   Kreb.    Krusty.    O
03.    1999/01/02.   Josh.    Milly.     S

CustomerO
ID.      NumberOfCr.   .....
02.       18273.       .....

Customer S
ID.     DateAsmp.    DateEnd.     TypeCon
01.     2020/12/12.  2021/10/07.    STN
03.     2020/11/22.  2020/12/30.    PLS
```

**WAY 2**

Create directly 2 different and separate tables, CustomerO and CustomerS:

```
CustomerS 
ID     DATEOFBIRTH.  NAME.   SURNAME.  DateAsmp.    DateEnd.     TypeCon 
01.    1989/07/12.   Sal.     Dallow.  2020/12/12.  2021/10/07.    STN
03.    1999/01/02.   Josh.    Milly.   2020/11/22.  2020/12/30.    PLS


CustomerO
ID     DATEOFBIRTH.  NAME.   SURNAME.   NumberOfCr.  
02.    1987/09/12.   Kreb.    Krusty.   18273.
```

---

Which approach do you think should I follow? why? And most important, the first approach is someway incorrect?

Comment: _two different types of customer_ This tells you exactly what you have/need to support.

Comment: @SMor so which one do you think is better?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:sql-server] as it conflicted with [tag:mysql] and SQL Workbench is a MySQL IDE, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The question depends on whether or not you need foreign key relationships to a "customer".  And I would guess that the answer is "yes".

That suggests that the first approach is better.  If you don't need foreign key relationships for "ordinary" and "special" customers, you might consider storing all the columns in the same table -- and not worry about the `NULL` values.

Comment: Yes, The foreign key "CustomerO_ID" is used in two tables (table 1 and table 2); while the foreign key "CustomerS_ID" is used in another table (table 3). Instead "CustomerID" fk is never used in other tables. (First approach)

Comment: There is no relationship between a table and "customer" in general, including both type S and type O. All the relationships are separately, or with CustomerS or with customerO

Comment: @Jenny . . . I suspect that in your system, you will want relationships between tables and `customers` in general -- transactions, contracts, or something like that.

Comment: No, consider that "customer" is just an example I reported to simplify and generalize my problem. so Fake that I don't need relationships between tables and customer in general